# ошибка в компоненте

Tags: yii2

Создаю компонент, будет использоваться для разборки и управления запросами:

```
namespace app\components;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Component;

class clsdb extends Component {

    //выполняем запрос
    public function query($sql) {

        $a_rows=Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
        return $a_rows;
    }
```

Тестирую в модуле:

```
$sql="select *from event ";
$a_rows=Yii::$app->$clsdb->query($sql);
```

Получаю ошибку:

ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function yii\base\Module::get(), 0 passed in /home/web/0popov.ints.net/htdocs/_projects/star/site/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php on line 139 and at least 1 expected

Подскажите в чем дела и как исправить.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил, не правильно вызывал:
Yii::$app->$clsdb->query($sql);
надо было
Yii::$app->clsdb->query($sql);